# Rx: Different TakeUntil behaviour with Timer based IObservable vs other IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm experiencing different behaviour with an TakeUntil and different implementations of IObservable as the parameter. I'm trying to understand WHY i get the different behaviour. Using Linqpad:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var byTimer = true;

    var ending = Observable.FromEvent<long>(
        handler => endingHandler += handler,
        handler => endingHandler -= handler);

    var s = new Subject<long>();

    using (var disposibleSub =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.2))
            .TakeUntil(byTimer ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)) : ending)
            .DumpLatest()
            .Subscribe(Observer.Checked(s)))
    {
        if (endingHandler != null)
        {
            int r = Console.Read();
            endingHandler?.Invoke(r);
        }
        var v = await s.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("Count of items: {0}", v);
    }
}

public event Action<long> endingHandler;
```

The one with the timer Count always returns the correct value. However, if I change it to use the FromEvent implementation, I always get 0. Obviously the difference is in the implementation of the two. I've also tried using a Subject implementation for the TakeUntil with the same results as the fromEvent.

The timer result is what I expected.

An explanation why would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `byTimer` is `true` then the `ending` observable never gets a subscription - remember that the observable pipeline is only instantiated when a subscription arrives - so in this case the `handler => endingHandler += handler` attach event code doesn't run and thus `endingHandler` is `null`. That means that the `Console.Read()` isn't called so the code drops immediately to `var v = await s.Count();` and this then catches all of the values passing thru `s`.

However, when `byTimer` is `false` then `endingHandler` is **not** `null` so then `Console.Read()` is called. When the console is read you immediately  invoke `endingHandler` which stops the observable and calls `OnCompleted` on the subject. So when it hits `var v = await s.Count();` it immediately gets a completed signal, missing all of the previously produced values, and thus you get a count of zero.

If you change your code to be like this:

```
    int r = Console.Read();
    if (endingHandler != null)
    {
        endingHandler?.Invoke(r);
    }
    var v = await s.Count();
```

Then the two observables behave exactly the same way.

If you then also go and change the `Subject` to `ReplaySubject` then the code should behave as you were originally expecting it to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about ReplaySubject, and the fact that it is timing related to when the subject is subscribed to. The key is only when you "await" are you then subscribing (as said https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/16 ).

Every time I think I get it, I mess up something trivial like this. Thanks for the extra eyes!